# + operator overloading error even though it is overloaded

Tags: c++

`pan.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "vector.h"

namespace math_ {
    
    void worldToScreen(const Vec2& world, Vec2& screen, const Vec2& offset);
    
}
```

`pan.cpp`

```
#include "pan.h"  
namespace math_{

    void worldToScreen(const Vec2& world, Vec2& screen, const Vec2& offset)
    {
        screen = world + offset;
    }

}
```

`vector.h`

```
#pragma once

namespace math_ {

    struct Vec2
    {
        Vec2(float x_, float y_);
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
        Vec2 operator +(const Vec2& other);
        Vec2 operator -(const Vec2& other);
    };

}
```

`vector.cpp`

```
#include "vector.h"

namespace math_ {

    Vec2::Vec2(float x_, float y_) :
        x(x_), y(y_) {}

    Vec2 Vec2::operator+(const Vec2& other)
    {
        return Vec2(this->x + other.x, this->y + other.y);
    }
}
```

`vector.h` is included in `pan.h`, where I am attempting to add two vectors in function `worldToScreen`, but I am getting an error `no operator + matches these operands` although it has been overloaded in vector.cpp file.

I don't believe this is a problem with overloading itself because when I try to do the exact same thing in a single file, everything works file. Its just when I try to split things up into different files that there are problems. There must be something I am doing wrong but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your overload is not marked `const`, but you are calling it from a `const Vec2&`:

```
struct Vec2
{
    Vec2(float x_, float y_);
    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;
    Vec2 operator +(const Vec2& other) const;
    Vec2 operator -(const Vec2& other) const;
                                  //   ^^^^^
};

Vec2 Vec2::operator+(const Vec2& other) const
                                    //  ^^^^^
{
    return Vec2(this->x + other.x, this->y + other.y);
}
```